# SQL statement's parameters not logged in console - spring boot v3 app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging, logback

I have read [this article](https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tips-how-to-log-sql-statements-and-their-parameters/) and googled a bit and came up with this `application.properties` file :

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/erp
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

# Default exception handling
server.error.include-message=always

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
logging.pattern.console=%clr(%d{yy-MM-dd E HH:mm:ss.SSS}){blue} %clr(%-5p) %clr(${PID}){faint} %clr(---){faint} %clr([%8.15t]){cyan} %clr(%-40.40logger{0}){blue} %clr(:){red} %clr(%m){faint}%n
```

### The Problem

I have is that my sql queries are shown but the binding parameter are still hidden "?".

i also noticed that even tho i have `logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder`'s loggin set to `trace` the lowest level i've seen is DEBUG, here is what my logs look like when i start the app :

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.0.1)

23-01-23 Mon 13:39:56.320 INFO  7900 --- [    main] ErpApplication                           : Starting ErpApplication using Java 17.0.1 with PID 7900 (G:\Workspaces\ERP-SYSTEM\ERP\target\classes started by DEV-ABDOU in G:\Workspaces\ERP-SYSTEM\ERP)
23-01-23 Mon 13:39:56.337 INFO  7900 --- [    main] ErpApplication                           : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
23-01-23 Mon 13:39:56.786 INFO  7900 --- [    main] RepositoryConfigurationDelegate          : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
23-01-23 Mon 13:39:56.827 INFO  7900 --- [    main] RepositoryConfigurationDelegate          : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 36 ms. Found 2 JPA repository interfaces.
23-01-23 Mon 13:39:57.200 INFO  7900 --- [    main] TomcatWebServer                          : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
23-01-23 Mon 13:39:57.217 INFO  7900 --- [    main] StandardService                          : Starting service [Tomcat]
23-01-23 Mon 13:39:57.218 INFO  7900 --- [    main] StandardEngine                           : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.4]
23-01-23 Mon 13:39:57.295 INFO  7900 --- [    main] [/]                                      : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
23-01-23 Mon 13:39:57.295 INFO  7900 --- [    main] ServletWebServerApplicationContext       : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 928 ms
23-01-23 Mon 13:39:57.397 INFO  7900 --- [    main] LogHelper                                : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
23-01-23 Mon 13:39:57.434 INFO  7900 --- [    main] Version                                  : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.6.Final
23-01-23 Mon 13:39:57.553 WARN  7900 --- [    main] deprecation                              : HHH90000021: Encountered deprecated setting [javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode], use [jakarta.persistence.sharedCache.mode] instead
23-01-23 Mon 13:39:57.637 INFO  7900 --- [    main] HikariDataSource                         : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
23-01-23 Mon 13:39:57.868 INFO  7900 --- [    main] HikariPool                               : HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@101c15ad
23-01-23 Mon 13:39:57.870 INFO  7900 --- [    main] HikariDataSource                         : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
23-01-23 Mon 13:39:57.914 INFO  7900 --- [    main] SQL dialect                              : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
23-01-23 Mon 13:39:58.514 DEBUG 7900 --- [    main] SQL                                      : alter table users_to_roles drop foreign key FKoapb2199m0cu5gdwiy4xibqqu
23-01-23 Mon 13:39:58.529 DEBUG 7900 --- [    main] SQL                                      : alter table users_to_roles drop foreign key FKolk7a861hdu0lghxspabptiqj
23-01-23 Mon 13:39:58.536 DEBUG 7900 --- [    main] SQL                                      : drop table if exists roles
23-01-23 Mon 13:39:58.545 DEBUG 7900 --- [    main] SQL                                      : drop table if exists users
23-01-23 Mon 13:39:58.556 DEBUG 7900 --- [    main] SQL                                      : drop table if exists users_to_roles
23-01-23 Mon 13:39:58.569 DEBUG 7900 --- [    main] SQL                                      : create table roles (id bigint not null auto_increment, name varchar(255), primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB
23-01-23 Mon 13:39:58.582 DEBUG 7900 --- [    main] SQL                                      : create table users (id bigint not null auto_increment, email varchar(255), password varchar(255), username varchar(255), primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB
23-01-23 Mon 13:39:58.594 DEBUG 7900 --- [    main] SQL                                      : create table users_to_roles (user_id bigint not null, role_id bigint not null, primary key (user_id, role_id)) engine=InnoDB
23-01-23 Mon 13:39:58.605 DEBUG 7900 --- [    main] SQL                                      : alter table users_to_roles add constraint FKoapb2199m0cu5gdwiy4xibqqu foreign key (role_id) references roles (id)
23-01-23 Mon 13:39:58.647 DEBUG 7900 --- [    main] SQL                                      : alter table users_to_roles add constraint FKolk7a861hdu0lghxspabptiqj foreign key (user_id) references users (id)
23-01-23 Mon 13:39:58.687 INFO  7900 --- [    main] JtaPlatformInitiator                     : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
23-01-23 Mon 13:39:58.695 INFO  7900 --- [    main] LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean   : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
23-01-23 Mon 13:39:58.981 WARN  7900 --- [    main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
23-01-23 Mon 13:39:59.149 INFO  7900 --- [    main] DefaultSecurityFilterChain               : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@47629063, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@3d67e3d3, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@209d0037, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@5f6ba085, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@14af57c3, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@758ac46, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@3b39bee2, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@3b7dd173, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@795949fb, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@6c569caf, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@30d944d8]
23-01-23 Mon 13:39:59.325 INFO  7900 --- [    main] TomcatWebServer                          : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
23-01-23 Mon 13:39:59.331 INFO  7900 --- [    main] ErpApplication                           : Started ErpApplication in 3.286 seconds (process running for 3.916)
23-01-23 Mon 13:39:59.419 DEBUG 7900 --- [    main] SQL                                      : select r1_0.id,r1_0.name from roles r1_0 where r1_0.name=?
23-01-23 Mon 13:39:59.451 DEBUG 7900 --- [    main] SQL                                      : insert into roles (name) values (?)
23-01-23 Mon 13:39:59.462 DEBUG 7900 --- [    main] SQL                                      : select r1_0.id,r1_0.name from roles r1_0 where r1_0.name=?
23-01-23 Mon 13:39:59.463 DEBUG 7900 --- [    main] SQL                                      : insert into roles (name) values (?)
23-01-23 Mon 13:39:59.467 DEBUG 7900 --- [    main] SQL                                      : select r1_0.id,r1_0.name from roles r1_0 where r1_0.name=?
23-01-23 Mon 13:39:59.468 DEBUG 7900 --- [    main] SQL                                      : insert into roles (name) values (?)
```

I didn't modify the logback config ( created my own logback.properties or logback-spring.properties ) i'm using what ever default config spring boot comes with.

Comment: I think you need `logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE` as well for values

Comment: Hibernate team have moved `org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder` to another package, now I believe the correct configuration is `logging.level.org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind=TRACE`. Please also check https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.1/logging/logging.html

Comment: it worked ! logging.level.org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind=TRACE fixed it @AndreyB.Panfilov
put it in an answer pls, i'll accept it right away